# Running Scheduled Task through GPO only once

Tags: group-policy, windows-task-scheduler

**Description:** we have a software that was deployed incorrectly on user's PC and we need to remove it and reinstall it.
we have created a GPO that runs a Scheduled task that removes the app using a script. and another to reinstall the app. the gpo is running on pcs in a specific OU.

**Problem:** because not all the users are connected at the same time and date. we want this task run for a specific period. however to run only once on a PC. now if we run a script to remove the tasks, the task will be re-added every time the group policy runs on the PC.

any suggestions on how to come around this other than manually removing the PC from that OU that the GPO on ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by simply setting the task trigger setting to "One time" rather than a regular schedule.

Then within Settings select the "Run task as soon as possible after a schedule start is missed", so if the machine isn't on at the time you select for the schedule, it'll run when it's next on.

For optional cleanup you can obviously set the GPO to "Apply one and do not reapply", and enable the scheduled task setting for "If the task is not schedule to run again, delete it after n days"